# asp.net reading asp:textbox values located in modal part after submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have modal div in asp.net page. This form has textboxes which I should check before submit. I do not see  the values inside btnReportModal_Click.

Can anyone help?

========= my aspx page ========================================

```
<div id="modalpopup" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Qty 1</span>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Qty 2</span>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnReportModal" class="hidden" Text="" OnClick="btnReportModal_Click" />
```

========= script =============================

```
function ShowPopup(param) {
    $(function () {
        $("#modalpopup").dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Submit": function () {
                        $("[id*=btnReportModal]").click();
                    },

                    "Close": function () {
                        $("#modalpopup").dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    __doPostBack(this.name, '');
                }
            });
        $("#modalpopup").dialog('open');
    });
};
```

======== code behind ================

```
Protected Sub btnReportModal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReportModal.Click
       dim txt as string  = txtQty1.Text
       'txtQty1.Text  - >> I see empty
End Sub
```

Comment: $("#modalpopup").dialog move the div id="modalpopup" outside the <form> tag. The values of your textboxes will not be send to the server. Try to review your dom structure after .dialog code was executed.

Comment: Maybe the selector $("[id*=btnReportModal]").click() isnt working. Open the modal and run $("[id*=btnReportModal]").click() in the console and see if you get a value, if not that may be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Anton. I have to leave it inside form because i am giving default values to textbox(es) before open  modal. I have got this working using $("#modalpopup").dialog({... }).parent().appendTo("form");
Thank you